# Postgres pl/sql function not supporting BIGINT[] as parameter

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I have pl/sql function in PostgresSql(version Postgres14) with following task=>
1)It will accept BIGINT[] as input parameter
2)based on Input Parameter it will scan my custom order table to see whether order id passed in exist in my order table or not
3)Will return Array of BIGINT[] type containing all invalid order id.

following piece of code written by me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.myFunction(
order_list bigint[])
RETURNS bigint[]
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
declare
  order_number BIGINT;
  order_count integer;
  invalid_order_number_arr BIGINT[];
begin
    FOREACH order_number IN ARRAY order_list                             
     LOOP                                                    
         Select count(*) into order_count from  
          myorder ord where ord.id=order_number;
    
        IF order_count = 0 THEN
           invalid_order_number_arr := ARRAY_APPEND(invalid_order_number_arr,order_number);
        END IF;     
     END LOOP;
    RETURN invalid_order_number_arr;
   end;
$BODY$;
```

From springboot jpa I am invoking it as below

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "Select myFunction(:orderIds)")
public Set<Long> getFailureOrderIds(@Param("orderIds") Set<Long> orderIds);
```

In Springboot Yaml file schema is defiend as below:

```
spring
 datasource:
  driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  url: jdbc:postgresql://myhost:5432/myDataBase?currentSchema=mySchema
  username: <myUser>
  password: <myPwd>
```

Connection with Db is established at startup of my SpringBoot application successfully.
But from service Layer whenever I am invoking  getFailureOrderIds(Setids) its giving following error:

```
PSSqlException: myFunction(param) doesnot exist.
```

From PgAdmin I have tested function is working fine.
**From Java Side cann't we pass java.util.Set as parameter to pl/sql function which accepting Array type parameter?**

Comment: Use CAST() in your SQL query to avoid the issue in Spring

Comment: @FrankHeikens can you pls explain a bit what kind of casting you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

Using a CAST() in the SQL should fix the issue:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "Select myFunction(CAST(:orderIds AS bigint[]));")
public Set<Long> getFailureOrderIds(@Param("orderIds") Set<Long> orderIds);
```

Comment: will it be CAST(:orderIds AS bigint) or CAST(:orderIds AS bigint[])?

Comment: @SumitGhosh: Sorry, I completely missed the array! It should be bigint[]

Comment: I already tried not fix,giving error, resultset cannot be cast bigint[]